# Writing a Double number for read it later with Scanner.nextDouble()

Tags: java, double, java.util.scanner

I have to write a Double number in a file and later read that file and that Double, but I have an ImputMismatchException. I have debugged the code and the problem is that the PrintWritter that I used to write the file, writes the number whith a dot, like this: 12.3 . And the Scanner.nextDouble() that I used to read that number returns the InputMismatchException if the input isn't like this: 12,3

Here is my code to write:

```
public void crearVentaNueva(int codigo, double precio, String nombre) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(archivoVentas, true);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

    pw.println(codigo + " dato " + nombre + " dato " + precio + " dato ");

    pw.close();
    fw.close();

    nVentas++;
    ventas.add(new Venta(codigo, precio, nombre));
}
```

And here is my code for read:

```
private void leerArchivoVentas() throws IOException {

    int codigo;
    double precio;
    String nombre;

    try {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(archivoVentas);
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(fr);
        nVentas = 0;
        while (lector.hasNextLine()) {
            nVentas++;
            lector.nextLine();
        }
        lector.close();
        fr.close();

        ventas = new ArrayList<Venta>();

        fr = new FileReader(archivoVentas);
        lector = new Scanner(fr);
        lector.useDelimiter("\\s*dato\\s*");

        for (int i=0; i<nVentas; i++) {

            codigo = lector.nextInt();
            nombre = lector.next();
            precio = lector.nextDouble();

            ventas.add(new Venta(codigo, precio, nombre));

        }

        lector.close();
        fr.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e) {

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(archivoVentas);

        ventas = new ArrayList<Venta>();
        nVentas = 0;

        fw.close();
    }
}
```

What could I do for don't have that ImputMismatchException and read the number correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to initialize the `Scanner` using a proper locale so that dots and commas are handled correct, like this:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(archivoVentas);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fr).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the overloaded `String.format` method and specify the appropriate locale, as in:

```
String.format(Locale.FRANCE, "%.2f", someDouble);
```